# Remember my choice for display as array in Eclipse C/C++

Tags: eclipse-cdt

In debug mode of Eclipse for C/C++, you can right-click on any watched expression that is a pointer and select "display as array". Then you're prompted for the array bounds and for the rest of *this* debug run, the watched expression is being displayed as an array according to these bounds.

When I terminate the process and start debugging again, it remembers my watched expressions, but pointers that were previously displayed as arrays will now be mere pointers again and hence, I have to re-cast all pointers in each debug run. In a recent project, this has become very tiresome.

Is there a way to make Eclipse remember the "display as array" choices for watched expressions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to be able to encode the fact that you want to look at the pointer as an array **in the expression string itself**.

Say you have an array as `int*` and you want to look at (most at) its first 4 elements.

In the `Expressions` tab, use one of the two following [syntaxes supported by GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html):

- `(*arr @ 4)`
- `((int[4])*arr)`

**The surrounding `(...)` parens above are important.**

You can do this in the `Expressions` tabs (watches), but not in the `Variables` tab.

[image: watching pointer as array]

Comment: That's perfect! Out of curiosity, though: Only the second syntax is working for me, the `*arr@12` syntax causes an error.

Comment: Was missing the parens.  I updated with the reference to GDB and put a new screenshot in while at it.  Thanks!